# How to prove the inverse image under an affine function is convex, if the image is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

Theorem in section 2.3.2 of Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook):

If $f:R^k \to R^n$ is an affine function and an set $ S \subseteq R^n$ is convex, the inverse image of  $S$ under $f$ defined as
$$f^{-1}(S)=\{\vec x|f(\vec x)\in S, x \in dom f\}$$
is convex.

$\text{My questions:1 How to prove the theorem? 2 I find an example: if}\ S'=\{(x,y,z)^T|x^2+y^2\le |z|，0\le |z| \lt \infty \} \text{, and if}\ f(\vec x)=[[1,0,0];[0,1,0]]\vec x(\vec x\in S'),\text{then } f(S')=S \text{ is convex. However the } S' \text{ is not convex. dose the example violate the theorem?}$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just cannot understand your question. It might help to be more clear about the result. What exactly are the premises, and what is the conclusion? You might find it helpful to see our [guide for MathJax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so that you can put mathematical symbols into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be an [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), and let $C$ be a convex set. We want to show that if $T(x) \in C$ and $T(y) \in C$ (i.e. $x,y \in T^{-1}(C)$), then $T((1 + t)x + ty) \in C$ holds for any $t \in [0,1]$.

To see that this holds, note that an affine transformation satisfies
$$
T((1 - \lambda x) + \lambda y) = (1 - \lambda)T(x) + \lambda T(y)
$$
for all $\lambda \in \Bbb R$. Thus, for any $x,y$ with $T(x),T(y) \in C$ and $t \in [0,1]$, we have
$$
T((1 + t)x + ty) = 
(1 + t)T(x) + t T(y).
$$
By the convexity of $C$, $(1 + t)T(x) + t T(y) \in C$, as was desired.